# Did Jesus infer the God of the Jews in Luke 11:11?

Tags: word-study

Being quite conversant with the scriptures, Jesus knew the name of the God (father) of Israel from (Deut 32:8,9) and that this God did send serpents among his children when they complained about food (Num 21:5,6).

Can the father of Deut 32:9 be likened to the father of Luke 11:11 or to that of 11:13? Since throughout the gospels, Jesus never used the proper name of God (Yahweh, Jehovah, etc.) only the title Father, to whom did he refer in either case?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Do you mean that Jesus never said "God"?  I do not understand this question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Omowright. God's name is embedded in Jesus' name. “the construction of theophoric names, starting with the letters “Jeho” is evidence that God’s name is actually Jehovah, (and that Christ’s name is actually Jehoshua) …..”– Smith’s 1863 “A Dictionary of the Bible”    Section 2.1

Comment: Luke 11.11 is not about which god, but an example of a father. The Num 21:5,6 example shows punishment due to unbelief. Deut 32:9 relation about allotting portion is not clear. Jesus means that all fathers give food for their children. You are going beyond the nature of this sentence if you compare it with God's punishment on sinners. or not providing food or rain for his people all the time.

Comment: - Michael16, I consider that a people with a cloud of fire over their heads every night would have acted out of hunger, thirst and frustration ( over the manna) than unbelief. Jesus is quite versed in the scriptures and I believe that there is always a link of his statements to the scriptures ...

Comment: That's your presupposition, which does not support reasonable interpretation. The context and verse clearly states they were speaking against God and Moses, they were ungrateful disbelievers. It is unreasonable that Jesus was condemning God in this verse just bec you can find a related cross reference of this verse.

Comment: @curiousdannii - would you reopen this question if it had a clearer title? Suggestion: "How can Deut 32:9 be reconciled with Luke:11:11?"  Since the OP is a new user I hope we can help him re-open this question since he is clearly perplexed with the issue.

Comment: @Omowright - When you say "he never used the name of God" do you mean never in any of the Gospels, or never in this passage. I suppose you mean the latter. Please clarify - it may help you get the question re-opened. It may also help if your remove the bit about the book of Daniel. This isn't really part of your question as I understanding. Please also work on the title question... I made a suggestion in my comment above.

Answer (score 5):

In Luke 11:11, the 'father' refers to the earthly father of a family. Jesus does not use the term 'father' allegorically to represent the Lord, rather, He emphasizes a contrast between the two.

Luke 11:13 NIV

> If you then, **though you are evil, know how to give good gifts to your children**, how much more will your Father in heaven give the Holy Spirit to those who ask him!”

In Luke 11:13, Jesus further elaborates on this contrast. When even an earthly father who may be imperfect or evil, provide good things for his children, the heavenly Father is certain to give the very best to whose who 'ask' him. The term 'ask', means 'pray', affirming Jesus' promise in Luke 11:9-10;

> 9 “So I say to you: Ask and it will be given to you; seek and you will find; knock and the door will be opened to you. 10 For everyone who asks receives; the one who seeks finds; and to the one who knocks, the door will be opened. (NIV)

Comment: The God of Abraham (Gen 17: 1) did not promise life (as in resurrection) or holy spirit. This is my confusion. The father to whom Jesus refers sends his spirit, the recipients of which, will say, as he does, Father (Abba) (Gal 4: 6).

Comment: @Omowright - among the promises to Abraham, one of them is the land his offspring will be given (Gen 12:7, 13:15, 24:7). Paul elaborate this offspring is Jesus (Gal 3:16). Abraham might have understood the land is lateral, which is the earthly Jerusalem. Paul told the church they should look upon the heavenly Jerusalem (Gal 4:26), a city that the Lord prepared (Heb 11:16, 12:22). The heavenly Jerusalem represents life, as God will dwell with them (Rev 21:3), no more tear and no more death (Rev 21:4). Inside the city there is 'river of the water of life'  and 'tree of life' (Rev 22:1-2).